# write raw bytes to serial using system settings with fewest lines of code (linux C)

Tags: c, string, serial-port, hex, byte

I'm trying to figure out a way to make my own program in C (with the fewest lines of code possible) which requires 4 parameters to be hexadecimal numbers. These numbers will then be converted to its raw string equivalent then sent down via the serial line (without waiting for serial input) at the baud rate determined by the system (via the stty command).

So the entire output to be sent down the serial line is as follows:

Source (in this example, character code for 123)
   Destination (in this example, character code for 46)
   Parameter 1
   Parameter 2
   Parameter 3
   Parameter 4
   Checksum (in this example, character code for 79)

So if I specify the following as the command-line parameters:

31 41 32 42

Then the 3rd through 6th bytes of data should then become:

1  A  2  B

While this code isn't 100% complete, is there a simpler way to take a set of  raw hex values in string format on the command line and turn them all into a single 4-byte string that I can attach to the 7 byte packet which I can send all at once down the serial port?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

//including this file causes "too few arguments to function "write"" error
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
  if (argc < 5){
      printf("4 hex values needed\n");
      return -1;
  }
  int fd=open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);
  if (fd < 0){
      printf("Can't open port\n");
      return -1;
  }
  unsigned char src,dest,byte1,byte2,byte3,byte4,checksum;
  src=(unsigned char)123;
  dest=(unsigned char)46;
  byte1=(unsigned char)strtoll(argv[1],NULL,16);
  byte2=(unsigned char)strtoll(argv[2],NULL,16);
  byte3=(unsigned char)strtoll(argv[3],NULL,16);
  byte4=(unsigned char)strtoll(argv[4],NULL,16);
  checksum=(unsigned char)79;
  write(fd,src);
  write(fd,dest);
  write(fd,byte1);
  write(fd,byte2);
  write(fd,byte3);
  write(fd,byte4);
  write(fd,checksum);
  close(fd);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a `buffer` that holds the message, and initialize the source, destination, and checksum bytes with an initializer. Then you can use a `for` loop to convert the arguments. Finally, `write` needs a length.
So the code between the `open` and the `close` can be implemented like this:

```
unsigned char buffer[] = { 123, 46, 0, 0, 0, 0, 79 };
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    buffer[i+1] = strtol(argv[i], NULL, 16);
write(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

Comment: I should have known this. I've been infused in optimizing machine code for a microcontroller lately that I've been trying to avoid loops to save execution time but I must realize that working with C, execution time isn't an issue and that I should use loops.